# parse http request "line by line" or "char by char"?

Tags: http, httprequest

I'm implementing a web server that only handles GET/POST/HEAD in C. I want to know what the general strategy for robustly parsing an incoming http request is?

Should I do it **char by char** or **line by line**?

- char by char approach seems inefficient, because I need a lot of code to track the state, eg when you see an "G", check if next is "E" and then "T"...
- line by line approach seems not robust. For example a client sends an incomplete request, eg missing "\r\n". Another example is that the request could be in different order `HTTP/1.1 GET /index.html` instead of `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`

Comment: If a client sends a malformed request, respond with Bad Request. You shouldn't handle malformed requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `HTTP/1.1 GET /index.html` is malformed - the name of the function (e.g. GET) must come first. As WTP suggested, I would return '400 Bad Request' in this case.

As for a missing \r\n: think what would you do if this case happened legally; for example, if the client started sending data, but just didn't finish sending.
The usual behavior in this case would be to wait for the user to complete sending the HTTP request, but maintain a timeout, so that malicious or malfunctioning clients won't bring your server down.
If the request wasn't completed in time, drop the whole request, and return '408 Request Timeout'.

Once that problem is dealt with, you'd best go with line-by-line parsing.